# How to find the canonical form (i.e., phase-free representation) of a unitary matrix?

Tags: gate-synthesis, compiling

While reading Weiden and others' recent paper: [Improving Quantum Circuit Synthesis with Machine Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.05622.pdf), I came across the notion of canonically representing a unitary matrix. More precisely, two unitaries differ only by a global phase is considered equivalent. On page 3, the authors gave a two-step procedure to derive the canonical representation of U by first finding a special unitary $V = e^{i2 \pi k/N}U^*$, where $N=2^n$. Here $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n$ is the number of qubits, and $U^*$ is the canonical representation of $U$.

My questions are summarized below.

1. The special unitary group is a subgroup of the unitary group: $\mathbb{SU}(N) \subset \mathbb{U}(N)$. In the case when some unitaries not having determinant equal to one, how does such "conversion" work?
2. How could we write $V$ with a scaler of the form $e^{i2 \pi k/N}$, when we are only given a unitary $U$ over $\mathbb{C}$?

Thanks!

Comment: if you're asking how to obtain a special unitary matrix from a given unitary one, you can just divide by the determinant: $V=U/\det(U)^{1/N}$ so that $\det(V)=1$.